# SpatiaLite / QspatiaLite: get subgroup row ids

Tags: sql, spatialite, qspatialite

I'm using QspatiaLite plugin to join polygon ids to points that are within those polygons. Now I' d like to get subgroup rownumbers for each subgroup of points with same polygon id! Like so..

```
grp_ID | sbgr_rowID | geom
--------------------------
1        1            ...
1        2
--------------------------
2        1
2        2
2        3
--------------------------
3        1
..
```

Here's my query:

```
   SELECT 
     plgns.ID AS grp_ID,
     -- ?subgroup row number? AS sbgr_rowID --,
     pts.Geometry
   FROM pts JOIN plgns 
   ON CONTAINS (plgns.geometry, pts.geometry)
   ORDER BY grp_ID, X(pts.geometry)
```